# 414 (Request-URI Too Long)

Tags: php, mysql

Пытаюсь вывести изображение из MySQL(BLOB)

```
 <img src="<?=base64_encode($value['IMG']);?>" class="card-img-top" alt="sdfs">
```

[image: Результат]

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?=base64_encode($value['IMG']);?>" class="card-img-top" alt="sdfs">
```